# optimization the network of highways

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I need to optimize the network of highways between cities from a given set –
assuming that city coordinates are given. I have given formula

`f (x) = at(x) + bd(x)`

where

- t(x)- total length of highways,
- d(x) - average length of path between two cities
- a,b - user provided parameters provided

I thought that the best possible way to do this is use of genetic approach. I want just to rotate with set of highways and check the outcome. But there arises my problem **how can i encode individual for genetich aproach?**

Comment: Isn't an individual just a bit vector wth one bit for each pair of cities. The bit is 1 if and only if the two cities are connected by a direct road.